# What does the Bible mean in Exodus 20:4 when it speaks of "the waters under the earth"

Tags: ten-commandments, cosmology

What does the Bible mean by "in the waters under the earth" ? What is found in the waters under the earth? Fish, gold, silver, and other creatures and precious stones, metals, and minerals in the waters under the earth?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works and what sort of question are appropriate.

Comment: @Dottard  Given that the tags the asker has chosen are "Genesis, Hebrew, Jesus, Luke, contradiction," and given that this forum is ostensibly for the interpretation of these scriptures, and given that the expression in question, "the waters under the earth," appear in the Bible--in the Ten Commandments, even--it seems clear that this question _is_ addressing a Biblical topic.  Add the fact that the asker is a "New contributor" here and may not understand all of what is generally expected, and I would urge a little clemency, courtesy, and Christian spirit.

Comment: @Polyhat - except for the following: The OP does not mention (1) commandments (2) any specific Bible passage; but that the OP does ask about a mythical creature not in the Bible, there is little that Biblical therapeutics can offer this question.  Further, neither the 10 commandments nor "waters under the earth" appear in Genesis.

Comment: @Dottard  If the asker is knowledgeable of all the facts before asking, then there were no reason to ask.

Comment: @Polyhat The rules are quite specific. And without those rules the site would quickly descend into chaos.

Answer (score 3):

In the creation account of Genesis 1, God created the firmament to divide the waters.  Following this, they are divided into the waters under the firmament, named "Heaven," and the waters which were above the firmament.

> And God said, Let there be a firmament in the midst of the waters,
> and let it divide the waters from the waters. (Genesis 1:6, KJV)
>
> And God made the firmament, and divided the waters which were under
> the firmament from the waters which were above the firmament: and it
> was so. (Genesis 1:7, KJV)
>
> And God called the firmament Heaven. And the evening and the morning
> were the second day. (Genesis 1:8, KJV)
>
> And God said, Let the waters under the heaven be gathered together
> unto one place, and let the dry land appear: and it was so. (Genesis
> 1:9, KJV)
>
> And God called the dry land Earth; and the gathering together of the
> waters called he Seas: and God saw that it was good. (Genesis 1:10,
> KJV)

In the Ten Commandments, these waters which were under the firmament, and which had been separated from the dry land (Earth), are also said to be "under the earth."

> Thou shalt not make unto thee any graven image, or any likeness of any
> thing that is in heaven above, or that is in the earth beneath, or
> that is in **the water under the earth**. (Exodus 20:4, KJV)
>
> For in six days the LORD made heaven and earth, the sea, and all that
> in them is, and rested the seventh day: wherefore the LORD blessed the
> sabbath day, and hallowed it. (Exodus 20:11, KJV)

These waters, then, were those that included all of the sea life that God had created on the fifth day of creation.

NOTE: The waters are below the level of the land, which is why they do not overflow the land.  In this sense, they are truly "under" the earth.  The Hebrew word here could also be translated as "beneath."

**Conclusion**

The fish, whales, and other sea life that God created in the sea are those things which are in the "waters under the earth."

Answer (score 1):

The Bible informs us that the pre-flood environment was different from what we experience today.  Between the waters on the surface of the earth and the waters above, there was an expanse (Genesis 1:6-7).  Genesis 2:6 says that a mist went up from the land and this watered the whole face of the ground.

During the lifetime of Noah and his family, there was a global flood, and Genesis 7:11 tells us where  the water came from:

> In the six hundredth year of Noah’s life, on the seventeenth day of the second month – ***on that day all the springs of the great deep burst forth and the floodgates of the heavens were opened.***

This suggests that great quantities of water came from below the earth as well as from above.  Although the Bible does not tell us any more about the waters that were below the surface of the earth, science does.  One view is that there may be an underground ocean three times greater than what we see on the surface of the earth.

> Some scientists think Earth's oceans formed when icy comets hit the planet. But new research suggests a different origin for the oceans: they simply seeped out of the center of the Earth.  The finding, published in Science, suggests that a reservoir of water is hidden in the Earth's mantle, more than 400 miles below the surface. Try to refrain from imagining expanses of underground seas: all this water, three times the volume of water on the surface, is trapped inside rocks.  https://ssec.si.edu/stemvisions-blog/there-ocean-below-your-feet

This 2020 article suggests that he water stored in the inner layers of Earth may be more plentiful — and important — than scientists previously thought.

> Under the extreme temperatures and pressures existing far underground, water breaks down into its constituent elements, hydrogen and oxygen, which are chemically bound to the rock’s crystal structure. But to geophysicists, it’s still water, regardless of the form it takes.  This begs the question: How much of this water is buried beneath the surface? The answer could help explain our planet’s suitability for life and tell us how all this water got here in the first place.  Source: https://www.discovermagazine.com/planet-earth/the-search-for-earths-underground-oceans

To answer your question, what does the Bible mean by "in the waters under the earth", the Bible is not specific.  However science indicates that there are no “seas” that contain fish or other living creatures.  The water may contain traces of minerals, metals and diamonds, but not in a form that could be extracted and instantly recognised.

We do not need to know the details.  After all, the Genesis account of creation and the flood is not meant to be a scientific paper.  Rather than looking into the bowels of the earth, we do better to lift our eyes to heaven to the creator of time, space, matter and all life and give Him our thanks.

P.S. Jesus Christ believed in the universal flood and took it as the type of the coming destruction of the world when He returns (Matthew 24:37-39; Luke 17:26-27). Hebrews 11:7 also refers to the flood during the time of Noah.

Comment: I don't interpret "water" so literally. Water in the Bible is most often used symbolically. Usually its associated with "words" or "speech". God is described as having a voice of "many waters". Jesus and Paul say believers are "washed with water" through the word. Jesus the word gives "living water". Attacks describe water in a negative way. The serpent "spews water out of its mouth" at the woman in revelation. King David says the floods and seas have "lifted their voices" against him in psalm 93. My understanding is it's talking about people/voices under the earth. That would be Sheol/Hell

Comment: @Marshall - I am aware that some people do not think the global flood was a literal event, but I do not share the view that "water" (in this instance) is symbolic. Your interpretation of people/voices under the earth being a reference to Sheol is one I have never heard before. Interesting.

Comment: Recently I have been doing a lot of study / prayer to understand specific key symbols of scripture and their meaning based on how they are used throughout the whole bible. 
Water is really one of the trickier ones and I'm still considering and meditating on it. So this post was really kind of thinking out loud while pondering the question and your response :)  Some of the symbols are easier to understand.
Trees = A person/being or group of people
Fire / Cloud = the holy spirt
So things like burning bush = being filled with the holy spirit (Jesus/God)
Water and its usage is trickier

Comment: Also despite the above I don't automatically believe there wasn't a global flood. God speaks in parable - but in the old testament he seemed to like to have the spiritual symbology of the parable - literally acted out. So I think its possible for potentially the symbolic meaning and literal meaning to both be true. But what happened physically is representing something else on a spiritual level. The water was real - but it represents something else. Just like later the wells they dug or met wives at were real - but they represented something else.

Comment: @Marshall - Do you have any research material/sources that might be used as an answer to this question?  I liked your question about red hair/scarlet thread and twins in the O.T.

Comment: I will try and put something together with scriptural references. :) I think I might need a few days to do so as like I said - my post on your answer was really me thinking out loud over the scriptures I had been studying on water while I pondered the question and your answer.  Think I will need to put my own thoughts together properly before I can gather the referrences and answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "in the waters under the earth" is used in context of forbidding idol worship and making graven images for idol worship.  In addition to the prohibition of Ex. 20:4 we find -

> *"16 lest ye do corruptly, and have made to you a graven image, a similitude of any figure, a form of male or female --*

> *17 a form of any beast which [is] in the earth -- a form of any winged bird which flieth in the heavens --*

> *18 a form of any creeping thing on the ground -- a form of any fish which [is] in the waters under the earth;*  (Deu. 4:16-18, YLT)

also see:

> *"`Thou dost not make to thee a graven image, any similitude which [is] in the heavens above, and which [is] in the earth beneath, and which [is] in the waters under the earth;"*  (Deu. 5:8, YLT)

Therefore, as they were forbidden to make graven images of either men or women, or any creature or object they could see in the heavens above, or in the waters under the earth, then the context has to include the objects or creatures they could see in the waters under the earth, ie: whales, fish, corals, dolphins, starfish, eels, etc.

We do know that some forms of life have become extinct due either to Noah's flood, or to excessive hunting by mankind, so some of the creatures that may have appeared very large or fearsome as to inspire awe are no longer with us.  But, the context was concerning making images of things they could see.

The implication of "the waters under the earth" is very interesting when examined more thoroughly.  If interested you might read my post "Is the Earth Hanging Upon Nothing>" here: [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2021/02/01/is-the-earth-hanging-upon-nothing/)